# Microservice, Queue vs HTTP request

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

We have a backend with a dozen of workers in `python` connected to `rabbitMQ` with `celery`. We have also the API gateway in `Django` with `postgresql`. The context between workers is handled by the DB.

We would like:

1. To decouple the DB and the workers,
2. To be able to make workers in Go.

We looked at the `microservice` infrastructure and this seems very interesting. What we don't understand is what kind of Request/Response pattern we should use and how we can handle the context of a request between workers without using a common db.

Microservice articles deal with `notifications` and `subscription`. Is this applicable to this situation or should we use HTTP request. Is the `RPC` pattern used? This pattern seems to be very heavy.

Comment: Why do you think the RPC pattern is heavy?

Comment: My understanding is that the RPC is creating dynamically the queue for response and this is not efficient. In celery it's recommended to deactivate the RESULT of worker to avoid this situation.

Comment: It seems that in the version 3.1 a new RPC backend is introduced to avoid the creation of a result queue per task but a result queue per worker (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend). This seems more efficient.